# Create static content selectors for Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

We are moving from GEB/Spock to Cypress for front end automation. With GEB/Spock, the page objects had static content. This was used to create the selectors for the page objects.

```
class LoginPage extends Page {
//private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginPage.class);


static url = 'login/'
static at = { title == "Login to TalentBank"}
static content = {
    backgroundImage { $("div [style*=\"background-image\"]") }
    logo { $(".center-img img") }
    emailHeader { $("#emailGroup:not([style*=\"none\"]) label") }
    emailTextBox { $('#emailGroup:not([style*="none"]) #email') }
    nextButton { $('#loginWithEmail') }
    pwdHeader { $("#passwordGroup:not([style*=\"none\"]) label") }
    pwdTextBox { $("#passwordGroup:not([style*=\"none\"]) #password") }
    loginButton { $("#loginWithPassword") }
    loginError(wait: true) { $("#loginError") }
```

In cypress, I'm unsure where to create and call these objects. Are the selectors supposed to be created as fixtures or as support files? I've read through the cypress documentation, but can't find what I am looking for.

Edit: 2/4

Under support, I tried creating a LoginPage.js file to contain the objects

```
// Login Page Objects
const emailTextBox = $('#emailGroup:not([style*="none"]) #email');
```

My test is under integration directory. I use the new constant in my test. There are no errors in my IDE, as the test appears to find the constant as it displays in the Ctrl+Space code completions.

```
describe('Successfull log in to the System', function() {

    it('Standard User - Successful log in ', function() {
       cy.get(emailTextBox).type('RodneyRuxin@mailinator.com')
```

When I run my test however, I get an error that says

> ReferenceError: emailTextBox is not defined

.

Comment: Have you tried using an array?

Comment: Either /fixutres or /support will work, fixtures would be simpler if you just want to store the selector strings as properties. If you need active methods/functions, a support file might be better. Post your tests, can then advise further.

Comment: I have added my test

Answer (score 4):

Okay so these are different selectors to interact with:

I would recommend a completely different class and then do an import of them? 
So for example a file called locators.js

which contains:

```
export const backgroundImage = () => cy.get("div [style*=\"background-image\"]");
```

then in your other file, you can import it like so:

```
import * as locators from "../locators/locators.js";
```

and call it like this (example):

```
locators.backgroundImage()
    .should('be.visible')
    .click();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I need to try this, but according to the cypress documentation, this will not work as Cypress does not return the element synchronously.
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Querying-Elements

Comment: Its how we've got all our elements set up in a couple of our frameworks and works fine.